# I get this (0, _reactNavigation.useTheme) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNavigation.useTheme)()', '(0, _reactNavigation.useTheme)' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make an authentication UI in react native and these are my files:
App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import EmailAccountLoginBlock from '../blocks/email-account-login/src/EmailAccountLoginBlock';
import { getStorageData } from '../framework/src/Utilities';
import AuthenticationStack from './Navigation/AuthStack';
import OtherStack from './Navigation/OtherStack';


class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await getStorageData('authToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const AppNavigator =createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: OtherStack,
      Auth: AuthenticationStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    },
  ));

export function App() {
  return (
    <AppNavigator/>
  );
}
```

AuthStack.tsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import EmailAccountLoginBlock from '../../blocks/email-account-login/src/EmailAccountLoginBlock';
import EmailAccountRegistration from '../../blocks/email-account-registration/src/EmailAccountRegistration';
import ForgotPassword from '../../blocks/forgot-password/src/ForgotPassword';
import VerifyAccount from '../../blocks/user-profile-basic/src/screens/VerifyAccount/VerifyAccountPage';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  EmailAccountLoginBlock: {
    screen: EmailAccountLoginBlock,
    navigationOptions: {title: 'EmailAccountLoginBlock', header: null},
  },
  EmailAccountRegistration: {
    screen: EmailAccountRegistration,
    navigationOptions: {title: 'CustomisableUserProfiles', header: null},
  },
  ForgotPassword: {
    screen: ForgotPassword,
    navigationOptions: {title: 'InvestMentExperience', header: null},
  },
  VerifyAccount: {
    screen: VerifyAccount,
    navigationOptions: {title: 'CategoryPerference', header: null},
  },
});
export default AuthStack;
```

And OtherStack.tsx is similar to AuthStack.tsk with other screens. I keep getting this error. I think this is an issue with the navigation. I've updated react-navigation, react-navigation-stack but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: If you correctly built this with typescript, the error suggests that the types for a package might be incorrect. First step I would take is to make sure dependencies are up to date.

Comment: As I said, I did update the packages.

Comment: If you are still having problems after that, it might be time to log a bug at the project that's causing the problem. It's weird though because the error is about a usage of `useTheme`, but I don't see it in the code you shared.